# R `optim` returns different results if run in parallel

Tags: r, optimization, parallel-processing

Is there any possible explanation for multiple `optim` instances with set starting values to return different results if run in parallel or one after another on a single core?

Basically, I do a rolling forecast with refitting of the model each time, so I can easily parallelize over the rolling windows, but the results are different if I do not parallelize...

Sadly, I don't have a simple reproducible example. I know that if I link to different BLAS then the results differ, so is there anything like different numerical precision / set of libraries used, that might cause this?

Comment: What routine in `optim` are you using?

Comment: OK, so it's not a RNG issue. Are they all cores on the same machine with the same BLAS and LAPACK installations?

Comment: Same machine, I have several installations of BLAS, but I was thinking that R somehow chooses the one it is using in the master process...

Comment: Could you provide en example that we can replicate. Otherwise, it is difficult to give an answer.